# R cannot be resolved to a variable : Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm new to Android and stuck with this error. I just imported an existing project to eclipse.

---

[image]

[image]

[image: The console shows these errors. I can't figure out the problem.]

Plz help me to solve this. I googled a lot. But i can't solve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

possible problems:

1- its possible that you have 2 resources that have the same name!

2- In one of your files you must have imported a wrong R package...

3- or you have a resource (like an image) that has the same name of a resource in android SDK files

4- try to rebuild and cleaning the project

I think your problem is No.2.. try to delete every import statement that has imported R package, then import the suggested R package yourself

Answer (score 0):

Probably try to clean the project if you are using eclipse.

Go to Project -> Clean. Select your project.

Also keep Build Automatically option in Project menu checked for future changes.

RK 
http://ctrlaltsolve.blogspot.in